# Button ContextMenu Styling in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button, wpf-стили

Я пытаюсь присвоить стиль для ContextMenu, чтоб было похоже на интерфейс Дискорда[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще, меня удивляет белая зона на меню итеме
почему она не воспринимает Background Setter?

Можете прислать примеры стилей для ContextMenu?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что я попробовал сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот, что получилось
на курсор не  реагирует, хотя IsMouseOver определён [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
можно как-то место под icon убрать?

не помогло даже это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто знает, как получить копию дефолтного стиля, как это делаться с кнопкой нажатием пкм на нее в визуальном редакторе, тогда прака шаблона->правка копии
(ведь контекстное меню отсутствует в визуальном редакторе)

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MidBrsh}"></Setter>
               <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MidBrsh}"></Setter>
                   </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>

           <Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MidBrsh}"/>
               <!--<Setter Property="" Value="{StaticResource MidBrsh}"/>-->
               <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
               <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MidBrsh}"/>
           </Style>

           <Style x:Key="ContextMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>

               <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
               <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}">
                           <MenuItem Header="SAS" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
                               <!--<Button Content="AAA"></Button>-->
                           </MenuItem>
                           <MenuItem Header="SAS2" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                       </ContextMenu>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
```

Вопрос к ответу D .Stark:
вот код:

```
<!-- ContextMenu separator style -->
           <Style x:Key="MenuSeparatorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
               <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
               <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
               <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
               <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
               <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323232"/>
               <Setter Property="Height" Value="5"/>
               <Setter Property="Template">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                           <Border Height="5" Margin="-2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF464646"/>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </Style>

           <!-- MenuItem style -->
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
               <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
               <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BEBEBE"/>
               <Setter Property="Template">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                           <Grid Name="Root" Height="27" Background="{StaticResource MidBrsh}">
                               <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Margin="10,0,0,0" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" TextBlock.FontSize="12" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"/>
                           </Grid>
                           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                   <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Background" Value="#505050"/>
                               </Trigger>
                               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                   <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Background" Value="#808080"/>
                               </Trigger>
                           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </Style>

           <!-- ContextMenu style -->
           <Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
               <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
               <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
               <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
               <Setter Property="Width" Value="170"/>
               <Setter Property="Template">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                           <Grid Background="Transparent">
                               <Border Margin="0,0,5,5" Background="{StaticResource MidBrsh}" BorderThickness="0">
                                   <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Margin="2"/>
                                   <Border.Effect>
                                       <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="3" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                   </Border.Effect>
                               </Border>
                           </Grid>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </Style>

           <Style x:Key="ContextMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>

               <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
               <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}">
                           <Grid Background="White">
                               <Grid.ContextMenu>
                                   <ContextMenu FontFamily="Calibri">
                                       <MenuItem Header="Скрыть имена"/>
                                       <MenuItem Header="Настроить канал"/>
                                       <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
                                       <MenuItem Header="Экспресс-приглашение"/>
                                       <MenuItem Header="Клонировать канал"/>
                                       <MenuItem Header="Создать голосовой канал"/>
                                       <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
                                       <MenuItem Header="Удалить канал" Foreground="#FFC83232"/>
                                   </ContextMenu>
                               </Grid.ContextMenu>
                           </Grid>

                       </ContextMenu>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
```

но вот, что я получил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так:

```
 <Style x:Key="ContextMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>

               <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
               <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ContextMenu FontFamily="Calibri">
                           <MenuItem Header="Скрыть имена"/>
                           <MenuItem Header="Настроить канал"/>
                           <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
                           <MenuItem Header="Экспресс-приглашение"/>
                           <MenuItem Header="Клонировать канал"/>
                           <MenuItem Header="Создать голосовой канал"/>
                           <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
                           <MenuItem Header="Удалить канал" Foreground="#FFC83232"/>
                       </ContextMenu>

                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
```

получил вот такое: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот ещё пробую:

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu FontFamily="Calibri" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MidBrsh}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Скрыть имена" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Настроить канал" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Экспресс-приглашение" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Клонировать канал" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Создать голосовой канал" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Удалить канал" Foreground="#FFC83232" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>

                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

и вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что делать с краями?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97260/discussion-on-question-by-anron-galaburda-button-contextmenu-styling-in-wpf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стили:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MidBrsh" Color="#202020"/>

<!-- ContextMenu separator style -->
<Style x:Key="MenuSeparatorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323232"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Border Height="5" Margin="-2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF464646"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- MenuItem style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BEBEBE"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Grid Name="Root" Height="27" Background="{StaticResource MidBrsh}">
                    <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Margin="10,0,0,0" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" TextBlock.FontSize="12" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Background" Value="#505050"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Background" Value="#808080"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- ContextMenu style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="170"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Border Margin="0,0,5,5" Background="{StaticResource MidBrsh}" BorderThickness="0">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Margin="2"/>
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="3" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Используем.

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu FontFamily="Calibri">
            <MenuItem Header="Скрыть имена"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Настроить канал"/>
            <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Экспресс-приглашение"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Клонировать канал"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Создать голосовой канал"/>
            <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Удалить канал" Foreground="#FFC83232"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

В принципе, похоже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не совсем понял, как юзать
сейчас добавлю в пост, посмотрите, если не сложно

Comment: Пример, который я привёл - установка `ContextMenu` для `Grid`. Если хотите запихать в setter, сделайте как написали в своём ответе ниже. У вас ведь всё получилось, как на моём скрине?

Comment: Кстати, вместо того, чтобы прописывать свойство `Style` у каждого элемента меню, добавьте все необходимые стили в ресурсы вашего `ContextMenuButtonStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример использования того, что показал D .Stark, спасибо ему

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu FontFamily="Calibri" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MidBrsh}" Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Скрыть имена" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Настроить канал" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Экспресс-приглашение" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Клонировать канал" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Создать голосовой канал" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                            <Separator Style="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorStyle}" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Удалить канал" Foreground="#FFC83232" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>

                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```