# C# WPF: Как установить задний фон и изображение в стиле для MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть стиль для `ContextMenu`, там я задал только задний фон и убрал обводку:

```
<Style x:Key="TrayIconStyle" TargetType="ContextMenu">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#222222"/>
       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

Для объекта `MenuItem` этого меню я тоже сделал стиль. По моей задумке он должен устанавливать **иконку** и **текст** в `StackPanel` и немного смещать текст при наведении мыши (`IsMouseOver`):

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#222222"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="_imgicon" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Icon,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" FontSize="14" Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="_txt" Text="{Binding Header,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="_txt" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="_txt" Property="Margin" Value="8 0 0 0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Однако все, что работает - это текст и его "анимация" смещения при наведении мыши. Иконка почему-то не отображается и имеется какая-то белая полоса слева, к которой я бы тоже хотел применить цвет фона `#222222`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В чем моя ошибка?**

---

Создание контекстного меню:

```
<ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource TrayIconStyle}">
    <MenuItem Header="Open">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="/ImgSrc/logo.ico" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: [Оно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1330254/373567)?

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) и еще пара ссылок: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15675382/12888024), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1011963/373567).

Comment: @aepot не совсем. Поменял стиль, указал цвета для конкретных элементов, но вид не поменялся. Только пропал сдвиг текста и также не показывается картинка :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На базе прошлого вашего вопроса делал пример для иконки системного трея, но потом вы удалили вопрос.

Разметка меню выглядит так.

```xml
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Padding="1" Background="#0f3c5a">
                            <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="Show Window" Command="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="Circle32x32.ico" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Hide Window" Command="{Binding HideWindowCommand}" />
    <Separator Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Margin="1" />
    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение целиком на Яндекс.Диске - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/tIydIVE0PVg8wQ

Comment: Нетрадиционные способы расшаривания проектов выбираете :) почему не гитхаб/аналоги? Куча же преимуществ

Comment: @АндрейNOP согласен, может быть, когда-нибудь. Пока так. :)